# Create random number and make a 2d array from that number

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I wrote a program to create random number and create a 2D array from the generated random number. But I get an error when I try to declare the 2D array.Please help me solve this. Below I mention the error and my program.

Error is:

> incompatible types:possible loosy convertion from long to int

The line causing the error is: `long[][] arr=new long[x][x];`

The program:

```
import java.util.*;
public class JavaApplication37 {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    long x=(long) Math.pow(10, randomGenerate(1, 5));
    System.out.println(x);

    long[][] arr=new long[x][x];
}

private static int randomGenerate(int min,int max){

    Random r=new Random();
    return r.nextInt((max-min))+ min;

     }

}
```

Comment: cast `x` to `int: ... new long[(int)x][(int)x]; `, or even better use `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you try this

```
import java.util.*;
public class JavaApplication37 {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int x=(int) Math.pow(10, randomGenerate(1, 5));
    System.out.println(x);

    int[][] arr=new int[x][x];
}

private static int randomGenerate(int min,int max){

    Random r=new Random();
    return r.nextInt((max-min))+ min;

     }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that size of array should be integer, so make your x `int`.

Answer (score 0):

Replace to:

```
int x=(int) Math.pow(10, randomGenerate(1, 5));
```